# Custom forms for a FE plugin in TYPO3 V 6.1.0

Tags: forms, plugins, typo3

**SOLUTION**

Inline Relational Record Editing is the answer. Handy stuff.

For [Documentation](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/irre_tutorial) 
:)

**QUESTION**

I created a front-end plugin using extension builder in TYPO3 6.1.0. For this plugin, extension builder of course generates few default forms in the backend. However, my intention is to have the forms customized. My plugin has 3 tables related it and all these have to be integrated to be inputted from one common form, than having individual forms, which is not ideal.

Do I configure my TCA stuff for this ?.. If so, please suggest me some good tutorials on that. 
Or will using FlexForm do the trick ?...also please suggest some good tutorials.

I also checked out Flux, but did not quite understand the architecture of it.

Thank You :)

**EDIT:**

I want forms to give the user to fill in records. Lets say I have an extension for creating Calendar Events. I need a form, in the TYPO3 backend, through which an administrator can add events and its details.

Comment: You mix the forms-stuff. There are Frontend, Backend, TCA and Backendmodule-Forms, what do you want do modifier.